# SSH local port forwarding using libssh

Tags: c++, ssh, portforwarding, libssh

**Problem**

I try to do local port forwarding using [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) with the [libssh-C++-wrapper](http://api.libssh.org/master/group__ssh__cpp.html). My intention is to forward port `localhost:3306` on a server to `localhost:3307` on my machine via SSH to connect via MySQL to `localhost:3307`.

```
void ssh_session::forward(){
    ssh::Channel channel(this->session);
    //remotehost, remoteport, localhost, localport
    channel.openForward("localhost",3306,"localhost",3307);

    std::cout<< "Channel is " << (channel.isOpen()?"open!":"closed!") << std::endl;
}
```

with `session` in the constructor of `ssh::Channel` being of type `ssh::Session`.

The code above prints `Channel is open!`. If I try to connect to `localhost:3307` using the [MySQL Connector/C++](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/) I get

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

**Observations**

- If I use the shell command `$ ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 me@myserver.com` everything works fine and I can connect.
- If I use `ssh::Session session` used in the constructor or `ssh::Channel channel` to execute remote shell commands everything works therefore the session is fine!
- The documentation of libssh (which is total crap for the C++ wrapper `libsshpp.hpp` since a lot of public member functions are not documented and you have to look into the source code) shows that `ssh::Channel::openForward()` is a wrapper for the C function `ssh_channel_open_forward()`
- The [documentation](http://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__channel.html#gae86b0704a1f2bdebb268b55567f7f47b) of `ssh_channel_open_forward()` states

  > **Warning**
  >   This function does not bind the local port and does not automatically forward the content of a socket to the channel. You still have to use channel_read and channel_write for this.

I think that could cause the problem. I have no problem by reading and writing in to the `ssh:Channel` but thats not how the MySQL Connector/C++ works.

**Question**

How can I achieve the same behaviour produced by the common shell command

```
$ ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 me@myserver.com
```

using libssh?

Comment: @Olaf: This is not about C++ code it is about a functionality provided by a C library that contains the whole logic and is widly known and a C++ wrapper which is basically nothing like `int mycppfunc(){return mycfunc()}`. Since `libssh` is one of only two reliable libraries for SSH written in C I think a lot of C programmers are familiar with it. I see no reason to remove the C tag.

Comment: Just using a C library from C++ code does not justifythe C tag. Otherwise pretty much every questrion will be a cnadidate for this tag, because all code eventually uses a C function - including Java and Python. Actually it can be doubted the C++ tag is valid either. But as you use that language, I'll leve it - in dubio pro reo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Warning
>
> This function does not bind the local port and does not automatically forward the content of a socket to the channel. You
>   still have to use channel_read and channel_write for this.

This is telling you that you need to write your own local socket code. Unfortunately, it doesn't do it for you.

The simplest implementation would be to `bind` a local socket, and use `ssh_select` to listen for events (e.g. new connection to `accept`, socket or channel events). You can keep your socket `fd`s aand `ssh_channel`s in a vector for easy management.

When you get any event, just loop over all the operations in a non-blocking way, i.e.

- try to `accept` a new connection, and append the fd, and a new ssh_channel (created as in your question) to your vectors.
- try to `read` all the socket `fd`s, and forward anything to the corresponding ssh channel using `ssh_channel_write` (make sure to setsockopt SO_RCVTIMEO to 0)
- try to read all the channels, using `ssh_channel_read_nonblocking`, and forward to the socket `fd` using `write`.

You also need to handle errors everywhere, and close the corresponding fd and ssh_channel.

Overall it's probably going to be too much code for a StackOverflow answer, but I may come back and add it in if I get time.

The tempting alternative to all that would be to just run `ssh -L ...` as a subprocess using `fork` & `exec`, avoiding all that boilerplate socket code, and benefitting from an efficient, bug-free implementation.

Comment: Thank's for your answer so far. I really tried to find a solution that doesn't need to create sockets manually but it seems like there is none. I wanted to avoid the password prompt that is used by all common `ssh` implementations therefore I want to avoid the usage of `fork` and `exec`. I know I could manage a workaround using `tty` directly but libssh seemed to be more elegant. It would be great if you could find the time to add a small snippet to clarify your intention of using socket `fd` and `ssh_channel` in a vector.

Comment: @joseph can you explain in case I use different Networking library like POCO, or wxWidgets? In that case I don't have fd. Also you can add pseudo-code if you don't have time to wrote real code and it will help a lot

Comment: Here is the code sample that do all the stuff:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811781/c-can-i-forward-port-for-external-application-with-libssh